# CXF don't accept SOAP req with default xml namespace

Tags: java, xml, soap, cxf, xml-namespaces

this one is accepted (auth namespace declared explicitly)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:auth="http://foo.pro/Auth/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <auth:login>
      <login>xxx</login>
      <password>xxxx</password>
     </auth:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

this one gives "Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://foo.pro/Auth/", local:"login"). Expected elements are <{}login>,<{}password>"

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soap:Header/>
            <soap:Body> <login xmlns="http://foo.pro/Auth/"
                           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <login>login</login>
            <password>password</password>
            </login></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

client can't be fixed, something should be done with cxf service side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is obvious. When you are defining a namespace: `http://foo.pro/Auth/` in your second example `<login>` and `<password>` elements which are wrapped with `<login>` belongs to `http://foo.pro/Auth/` namespace. Because your are declaring it in the root `<login>` tag with `xmlns`, so everything which is in it, belongs to this namespace: `http://foo.pro/Auth/`. As in your first example you are only assigning root `<login>` element via `auth` prefix which points to: `http://foo.pro/Auth/` namespace and the others which are inside it does not have any namespace assigned to them that is way your second example gives you an error.

Comment: ok, this avoided my attention, will try to fix from the client side.